# Lightning Web Component That Allows Text Input and Dropdown

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, html5, css3

Is there a LWC that allows me to utilize it as a text input field and also a dropdown menu?

I need to display results as a dropdown but also allows user text input to search.

Answer (score 3):

You likely need a typeahead or text lookup. There are a lot of components built by the people. It won't look exactly as drop-down. If you want to build that from scratch then you can use the lightning design system to create one.

In simplest approach, standard HTML input tag also have a list attribute that can help achieve this. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: Thanks for your advice, let me check out the w3 link you sent also.